# Conditionally trigger Button navigation in Material UI 1.0

Tags: material-ui

Material UI 1.0 (`1.0.0-beta.41`, specifically) provides a nice API for using buttons to trigger navigations:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import Button from 'material-ui/Button';

<Button component={Link} to="/open-collective">
  Link
</Button>
```

[Source](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/buttons/#third-party-routing-library)

My question: Is there a way to trigger the navigation, only after some other conditions are true? E.g. upon clicking the button, I do some form validation. Only if the form is complete should the button route to another page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditionally linking with react-router Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37218833/conditionally-linking-with-react-router-link)