# How to prevent someone to be redirected by <Link> from react-router-dom in case of some condition

Tags: reactjs, redirect, hyperlink, conditional-statements, react-router-dom

I have `<Link` that wrapping `"search"` button. when i click the button it's redirect me to the right place and everything ok.
the problem is that the search is based on some parameters, and i would like that only in condition that all of the parameters are filled it will work,
otherwise, i would like it to represent some msg.

what is the right way to accomplish this mission?

```
export class SubmitSearch extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Link
          to=`SOME PATH`>
          <Button variant="success">
            Search
          </Button>
        </Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: This may be is what you are looking for [conditionally-linking-with-react-router-link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37218833/conditionally-linking-with-react-router-link)

Comment: @HiRenS I saw that, but it doesn't help me unfortunately.
I want that the search button will be shown all the time. and in some case it will return msg, and in another case it will work and redirect me next.